# Slack bot permission to delete a message

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm writing a bot that will make some channels read-only for most users except for a group of admins. This means the bot needs permission to delete users' messages. When I try to delete a message with the bot, I get a `cant_delete_message` back. I understand that I need another token, one that starts with xoxp for that (I already have xoxb).

I've read a bunch of tutorials and docs on this topic, but I think they mostly don't go well with my use-case: I would not like to create and register an app with Slack as this will only be used internally.

How can I get this master token?

Answer (score 5):

In order to be able to delete message from other users by your bot you need the following:

1. Your Slack app needs to be installed by an admin
2. You need to use the **user token**, not the bot token to call [`chat.delete`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.delete)

You get the user token during the installing process for your Slack App where you will always receive two tokens: a user token (which is called access token) and a bot token.

Note that you will need a Slack app (that includes a bot user) - it will not work with a custom bot user.

Example from the [offical documentation](https://api.slack.com/bot-users#adding_bot_users) on bot users:

```
{
    "access_token": "xoxp-XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX-XXXXX",
    "scope": "incoming-webhook,commands,bot",
    "team_name": "Team Installing Your Hook",
    "team_id": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "incoming_webhook": {
        "url": "https://hooks.slack.com/TXXXXX/BXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX",
        "channel": "#channel-it-will-post-to",
        "configuration_url": "https://teamname.slack.com/services/BXXXXX"
    },
    "bot":{
        "bot_user_id":"UTTTTTTTTTTR",
        "bot_access_token":"xoxb-XXXXXXXXXXXX-TTTTTTTTTTTTTT"
    }
}
```

To verify here is what the official documentation says on the topic:

> When used with a typical user token, may only delete messages posted
>   by that user.
>
> **When used with an admin user's user token, may delete
>   most messages posted in a workspace.**
>
> When used with a bot user's
>   token, may delete only messages posted by that bot user.

Comment: So I created a Slack App here: `https://api.slack.com/apps/`. I've added a bot here `https://api.slack.com/apps/[app-id]/bots`. Is this what I was supposed to do?
When I go to my Apps here `https://[company].slack.com/apps/manage`, I don't see my app to be able to add it. What now?

Comment: Technically this is a new question :-) But yes, first 2 steps are correct. Then you need to install it to your workspace. Adding from "Manage Apps" only works for public apps, but you can go to `https://api.slack.com/apps/[app-id]/install-on-team` to install your internal Slack app directly. See also documentation [here](https://api.slack.com/slack-apps#installing_apps)